# Negative energy of infalling particle in a Reissner-Nordström black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, energy-conservation, charge, reissner-nordstrom-metric

If we have a Reissner-Nordström black hole with Q > 0, then what charge (positive or negative) must an infalling charged particle have in order for the particle to be able to obtain negative energies at the horizon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy of a charged particle with charge q, infalling into a Reissner-Nordström black hole with charge Q is given by $\epsilon = (p-qA)\cdot \zeta_{(t)}$. In this expression $p = p_\mu dx^\mu$ is the momentum of the particle, $A = A_\mu dx^\mu = -\frac{Q}{r}dt$ is the electromagnetic gauge field, and $\zeta_{(t)} = \zeta^\mu_{(t)} \partial_\mu$ is the timelike Killing vector, hence we can take $\zeta^\mu_{(t)} = [1,0,0,0]$, so that $\zeta_{(t)} = \partial_t$. Note $dx^\mu(\partial_\nu) \equiv \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^\nu} = \delta^\mu_\nu$, hence $dt(\partial_t) = 1$ and $dr(\partial_t) = 0$.

We will take the metric to be $ds^2 = f(r)dt^2-f^{-1}(r)dr^2$ and we will ignore $\theta$ and $\phi$ by assuming a purely radial trajectory for the particle as it approaches the horizon at $r = r_h$, where $f(r_h) \equiv 0$. We do not need to specify $f(r)$ for our problem but it is the standard one for the Reissner-Nordström black hole.

Now we evaluate $\epsilon = (p_t - qA_t) = (p_t + \frac{qQ}{r}) = (f(r)p^t + \frac{qQ}{r})$, where we used $p_t = g_{tt}p^t = f(r)p^t$. Given $ds^2 = d\tau^2 = f(r)dt^2-f^{-1}(r)dr^2$ and $p^\mu \equiv \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$, we can use the first to write $\frac{dt}{d\tau} \equiv \dot{t} \equiv p^t = (\frac{1}{f(r)}+\frac{(p^r)^2}{f^2(r)})^{1/2}$. Substitution gives $\epsilon = (f(r) + (p^r)^2)^{1/2} + \frac{qQ}{r}$. Given $\epsilon$ is a constant of the motion we can evaluate it at $r = r_h$, where $f(r_h) \equiv 0$ and $p^r(r_h) = 0$ from $d\tau^2 = f(r)dt^2-f^{-1}(r)dr^2$.

We have $\epsilon(r_h) = \frac{qQ}{r_h}$, from which we see that **if we want $\epsilon < 0$, we need $qQ < 0$ and so if $Q > 0$ then $q < 0$**.

For some discussion see page 10 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3657.